# how to focus different `regions`(Ctrl-a S) via mouse-click in `screen`?

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

When I start `vim` in a `screen` session, and activate the mouse:

```
:set mouse=a
```

the mouse remains disabled. I cannot switch tabs via mouse click.

How can I configure `screen` so that mouse support in `vim` works?

---

**Edit:**
I guess the version of my `screen` is too old. When I upgrade it, mouse works fine in vim.

I still want to know how to focus different `regions`(`Ctrl-a S`) via mouse click.

Comment: Does mouse support works outside `screen`? I didn't have to change any settings.

Comment: @phunehehe mouse works fine when `:set mouse=a` outside of `screen`

Comment: @kev Post your `.screenrc`. Something in it and/or related to it, `$TERM`, is interfering with `vim`.

Comment: @nicerobot I don't have a `.screenrc`.

Comment: @kev Doesn't that kinda defeat the purpose of using `screen`? I mean, the main reason to use something like `screen` versus GUI terminals is to keep your hands on the keyboard constantly. If you're going to be using the mouse, just use a GUI terminal that supports tiling of its windows. Honestly, i can switch between regions far faster with the keyboard than i can by reaching for the mouse.